# Files for synchronizing project not apearing

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync

I'm trying to synchronise (upload) alterations (new fields) from QGIS to Qfield. They were sychronising fine and then now it seems to freeze and either only a few of the files (the newly created ones) or no files show on the menu for sychronizing to the cloud. I'm obviously doing something wrong as it appears on the cloud but not on qfield app itself.

I'm very much a novice to qgis. Learning through making a lot of mistakes unfortunately.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated about what to try to resolve this.